# What is an appropriate translation for "Remove Follower"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation, english-comparison

The translation I have been given for "Remove Follower" is "Follower remoto".  This doesn't seem correct to me.  This is the title on a button that removes or deletes a "Follower" (subscriber) from a list.

"Remoto" seems like "removed" as in "far removed" which I think is not the right meaning.

There are a lot of translations for the word "remove".  There's togliere, levare, allontanare, rimuovere, eliminare but I don't know which is the best for this.

Comment: Whoever gave you that translation probably misread “remove” for “remote”.

Comment: *Remoto* means the same as *remote* in English. The verb *rimuovere* and the adjective *remoto* have the same Latin origin (*moveo, movi, motum, movere*, with the intensive prefix *re*), but now they have rather different meanings. I'd go with *rimuovi* or *elimina*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "follower" you mean a social network friend (e.g. twitter users), we're using "Rimuovi follower". You can leave "follower" as is if you don't need a complete translation.

Comment: Sorry, who is "we"? And did you by chance mean "e.g." instead of "i.e."?

Comment: I'm really sorry.. we = Italians, and yes, e.g.

Comment: That's really such a bad translation to receive a downvote? I've seen the word "follower" in some Italian sites, such as https://it.forums.wordpress.com/topic/mail-ai-follower-finiscono-in-spam?replies=1, so that "rimuovi follower" sounds OK to me.

Comment: Didn't downvote (nor upvote), but, while _rimuovi follower_ is possibly the translation the OP is looking for, this answer is poor in terms of additional information.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote, this is helpful.

Comment: The sad truth is that this is the only viable option. There is no workable solution for translating "follower" as in "Twitter follower." I upvote.

Answer (score 3):

A stricter translation would be "Rimuovi Seguace", but since "Follower" has never been translated into Italian on mainstream social networks (probably due to the fact that it's a rather old fashioned old, and would sound better if you were talking about religious followers - "Seguaci" or "Discepoli"), in the end you can keep it "Rimouovi Follower"

EDIT: Facebook does translate "Follow" with "Segui" (world related to "Seguace", the one who segue/follows), but solves the problem avoiding the term Followers

Answer (score 2):

If by *remove follower* you mean  *remove subscriber*  from a list, you can use:

> - *eliminare/rimuovere l'abbonato* (dalla lista)

*Levare and togliere* could also work, but they are more  colloquial, while *allontanare* is not correct in the context.